# Tilt the Three.js Orbit camera's plane of rotation *or* keep Trackball camera's Y-axis aligned "up"

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, vectormath

The Three.js Orbit camera keeps the camera pointed "up" while looking at a "center" point. I can use camera.up.set() to change the camera's up vector, but this doesn't change the the camera's plane of rotation when orbiting.

Is it possible to tilt the Orbit camera's plane of rotation, or should I do this some other way?

Edit: I believe keeping the Trackball camera's Y-axis always aligned to its "up" vector would accomplish the same thing, is that possible?

Comment: i always thought that the trackball-Controls are the orbit controls smaller brother in that you have a fixed up-axis for the orbit controls and not for trackball, so have you tried trackball controls for your use-case?

Comment: I hadn't, because I wanted a fixed up axis – but maybe it would be easier to modify the trackball's behavior in this case.